# Script works when run manually, but trigger doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I had many Google Script projects that worked reliably with triggers on form submit. After a few months away from my desk, I created a project and, although the script works as expected when I manually run it, the trigger (on form submit) has no effect. Hours later I receive email reports listing that the error is "Authorization is required to perform that action." I see that others have had errors of this type before. I've tried logging off and back on, and to delete the project triggers and adding them back.

Any help will be much appreciated--my organization had come to rely on trigger-run scripts. I attach my script below, should it be something in the script itself that is the problem.

```
function sendLike() {
    var mainSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('12345');

    var sheet = mainSheet.getSheetByName('Likes');
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    
    var timestamp = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();
    var teacher = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();
    var grade = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3).getValue();
    
    if (grade == "sixth") {
      gradeColumn = 4;
    } else if (grade == "seventh") {
      gradeColumn = 5;
    } else if (grade == "eighth") {
      gradeColumn = 6;
    }
    
    var studentName = sheet.getRange(lastRow, gradeColumn).getValue();

    var positiveDescription = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 7).getValue();
    
    var roster;
    var rosterSheetLastRow;
    var rosterArray;
    var teacherRow;
    var currentTally;
    var updatedTally;

    var rosterSheet = mainSheet.getSheetByName(grade);
    
    var receivedLikeSubject = "You got a Like!";
    var receivedLikeMessage = "Well done!";
      
    //only accept likes from staff (in the staff_roster sheet)
    var staffFlag = false;
    var teacherRosterSheet = mainSheet.getSheetByName('staff_roster');
    var staffLastRow = teacherRosterSheet.getLastRow();
    var teacherArray = teacherRosterSheet.getRange(2, 1, (staffLastRow - 1)).getValues();
    var teacherTotalLikes = 0;
    var teacherNewLikes = 0;
    var staffRow = 0;

    var j;
      for (j = 0; j < staffLastRow; j++) { 
        if (teacherArray[j] == teacher) {
          staffFlag = true;
          staffRow = j + 2;
        }
      }
    
    if (staffFlag) {   
      //tally counter
      rosterSheetLastRow = rosterSheet.getLastRow();
      rosterArray = rosterSheet.getRange(2, 1, (rosterSheetLastRow - 1)).getValues();
      var studentRow = 0;
      var currentTally = 0;
      var studentId = "";
      var studentEmail = "";
      var newTally = 0;

      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < rosterSheetLastRow; i++) { 
        if (rosterArray[i] == studentName) {
          studentRow = i + 2;
          currentTally = rosterSheet.getRange(studentRow, 3).getValue();
          newTally = currentTally + 1;
          rosterSheet.getRange(studentRow, 3).setValue(newTally); //update likes tally in grade roster
          studentId = rosterSheet.getRange(studentRow, 2).getValue();
        }
      }
      
      teacherTotalLikes = teacherRosterSheet.getRange(staffRow, 2).getValues();
      teacherNewLikes = parseInt(parseInt(teacherTotalLikes) + 1);
      teacherRosterSheet.getRange(staffRow, 2).setValue(teacherNewLikes);

      studentEmail = studentId +"@asdf.org";

      MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: studentEmail,
      subject: receivedLikeSubject,
      htmlBody: receivedLikeMessage
      });
    }   
  }
```

Comment: Did you create the trigger in Spreadsheet Project or in the Form Project?  I wonder why you did not use the event object values array or namedValues object

Comment: I could be missing something but I don't see any obvious reason for trigger not working unless you have setup the form trigger instead of the Spreadsheet Trigger but presumably you know the difference.

Comment: I set the trigger for the the spreadsheets that receives responses on form submit. Although this script is new, triggers have stopped working for me on older projects that were working reliably for months.

Comment: Have you been using V8 on all of the scripts that have suddenly stopped.  You can also set up the trigger to send error messages immediately

Answer (score 0):

###### I don't use google apps script much anymore but I think the problem is you haven't allowed authorization, to fix this do the following.

- In the top right corner click the 'Deploy' dropdown
- Click 'New Deployment'
- Then set the deployment type (gear on far left of popup) to 'Web app'
- Set the 'Execute as' dropdown to 'Me'
- Set the 'Who has access' to 'Anyone'
- You should get a screen that looks like this:[image]
- click 'Authorize access' and then click 'Done'

###### On top of this make sure that you create the google app script from the form and not the other way around, top do that do the following:

- Open the form
- Click the three dots in the top left
- Click script editor

Comment: But the op has not provided any doGets or doPosts nor have they said anything about webapps.  Maybe they have not authorized the script but the op said they have done many google script projects.  I'm just curious why you chose to go down this path without first asking the op?

Comment: As I stated in my answer, I don't use google apps scripts much anymore and am just merely trying to give a suggestion. When I had similar problems, this is exactly how I fixed them every single time. Also, if OP wants a different path, then they can comment on this answer with more details. Additionally, it does not matter how many times you do something, as you can always make those small mistakes.

Comment: Yeah but if the OP is not creating a webapp your answer is not the answer.  You do not have to setup a deployment to create a trigger or a function.

Comment: Ok... then OP doesn't have to do my answer?

Comment: I appreciate the insight. I was not prompted to provide authorization. I worked from the spreadsheet's script editor, and I had on my end provided authorization, which I guess it's why the script runs when I execute it manually.

Comment: @gonzalo2000 Just looked it up, and it seems like they might have changed how form triggers work. Here's a link to the new (I think) event handler. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder

Looking through your code, I don't see the new event handler but maybe I'm missing something or you didn't add it to your post.

Comment: @LuniZunie Thanks for the insight. I added the event handler, and when I run it I got a request for Authorization, and it created a second trigger to run the function on form submit, but it still did not execute the function.